# Android - как БЫСТРО сохранить ОГРОМНЫЙ объём данных?

Tags: android, java

Есть массив: `int[][] data = new data[32769][257]`, всего в нём `8388608` записей. Данные сохраняются в формате `[a] [b] значение_в_ячейке`.

Если способ, чтобы быстро сохранить эти данные в файл? Пробовал базу данных SQLite - слишком медленно, а обычный файл будет весить очень много. Есть ли действительно быстрый способ сохранить такой огромный объём данных?

К рассмотрению принимается всё - хоть SharedPreferences :)

Comment: (32769 * 257 * 4) / 1024 / 1024 = 32.13 Мб — это и есть ваш ОГРОМНЫЙ объём данных?

Comment: а Вы думаете, что база будет весить меньше? там данных на 44мб. Старые андроиды даже не потянут столько сразу в памяти. Что там храниться? может можно более простые способы применить? но без знания внутренностей - очень сложно. Не примитивный ли excel пытаетесь сделать или это просто звук записали?

Comment: Для меня - да.

Comment: >> @KoVadim, я пытаюсь запихнуть в файл сохранение от игры

Может стоит пересмотреть формат сохренения игры ?

Comment: смутно мне вериться, что эти все 44мб там реально нужны. Скорее всего там 90% данных - нули. А то и все 99%. Так может сохранить ненулевые ячейки?

Comment: @SuperCreeper, это действительно весьма небольшой объём данных для SQLite. Полагаю, вы неправильно организовали запись. Почитайте про `batch inserts` и транзакции.

---

Ну и присоединяюсь к вышеизложенным сомнениям — не верится мне, что все эти данные действительно нужны для сохранения. А если это и так — значит, пришла пора пересмотреть архитектуру.

Comment: Тогда такой вопрос: можно ли разнести запись на 2 отдельных потока (как раз в 2 раза увеличиваю скорость записи)? Например, первый поток будет записывать в базу первую половину данных, а второй всё остальное. Не взорвётся ли девайс от этого?

Comment: девайс не взорвется, но скорость скорее всего не увеличится. Потому что сама база то однопоточная. Придется делать блокировки, которые съедят все.

Честно - скорость не получите, а проблем - целую кучу.

Comment: Всем спасибо за оказанную помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как всегда нападки на sqlite .... готов спорить транзакции Вы не использовали

---

Соглашусь с [[@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim), скорее всего много лишних данных. Несколько маленьких советов по sqlite, если кто добавит буду только рад:

1. Используйте контракт для описания данных - по сути обычный статичный класс с описанием нужным свойств и гетеров/сетеров (IDEA их может генерировать автоматически) и описания констант имен таблицы и полей (я это выношу в отдельный класс внутри этого, но не принципиально, возможно Вам удобнее как то по другому организовать данные )
2. Опишите в отдельном классе контроллер - в нем статичные методы для работ с бд, в них же удобно обрабатывать ошибки и многое другое
3. Возможно сейчас это Вам и не нужно, но обратите внимание на Content Provider, многие вещи с ним  намного проще и удобнее (холиварное утверждение)
4. Для быстрой работы используйте транзакции - настроек sqlite и изначально она настроена на надежность, а не скорость

Comment: Если уж зашла речь о sqlite, то спрошу: правда ли, что лимит записей в sqlite равен 10000?

Comment: в sqlite? лимит записей на таблицу? вряд ли. Вот только на днях делал проектик, который записал порядка 16000 записей и никаких проблем/осложнений.

Comment: @SuperCreeper, а что вам мешает заглянуть в документацию? Там ясно написано, что лимит самого SQLite 2^64 записей в одну таблицу, остальное — ограничения платформы/OS/дискового пространства.

Comment: Тоже ничего подобного не слышал, как минимум такие не серьезные размеры для бд было бы странно

Comment: @KoVadim, я просто начал работать с SQLite только вчера, ещё во многом не разобрался :)

А вот этот ответ (stackoverflow.com/a/4760447/2718135) на стаке с фразой о лимите в 10000 реально напугал.

Comment: На 150к записей делал табличку...  
http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html  
Пункт 13

Comment: статьи по ссылке там нет, но я нашел ее копию. Человек пишет, что он использовал адаптер к базе и если в базе больше 12000 записей, то getCount работает медленно (до 2 секунд). А это плохо, так как адаптер работает с главного треда.

По факту. Это не проблема базы. Это проблема адаптера. Если кому то нужно больше записей, то он скорее себе напишет специализированный адаптер. Один универсальный адаптер на 10 и 1кк записей написать сложно. Для большинства людей стандартного адаптера хватит с головой.

Если работать с базой без адаптера, то никаких проблем.